# Need to download font from the url using swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, fonts, download

I am getting 'font' url in response to one of my API requests with extension (.ttf). When I researched on how can I use it, it seems I need to download the font file from that url and then use the downloaded 'Font file' in my app. But I dont know how this whole process is done.

Example: Any image thats downloaded from a url and then used.

Please can anyone help me with some inputs on what inbuilt methods can I use or how do I get the url downloaded and use its font in my app.

Comment: I feel like I've seen an extremely similar question before...

Comment: @aheze Yes, but that is not answered yet.. so had to add another one

Comment: Ah, so did you delete and re-ask? Better to edit your original question instead. And once you get to 75+ reputation, you can [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to get more attention.

Comment: @ElTomato Edited my question and explained a little more on what I am looking for.

Comment: @Sanchita - please review [ask]. You need to show what you've tried already. Have you searched for how to download a file and done that successfully? If not, start there. If so, what code are you trying to use to dynamically load and use the downloaded font / ttf file? What's not working? People here on Stack Overflow are happy to help you, but you cannot expect someone to do your work for you.

Comment: @DonMag , I am just asking for inputs on the above scenario, I haven't asked for a complete code, small suggestions would also help. I understand that the question is not mentioning all the details, because I don't know how its done (I am just a beginner) and hence couldn't try anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is answering itself...

Step 1:

- **Search** (using google or your favorite search engine) for `swift download file to documents directory`
- You'll get many, many results. Go through a few of them, find one you like.
- Implement that in your code -- downloading the `.ttf` file.

Step 2:

- **Search** (using google or your favorite search engine) for `swift register a downloaded font programmatically`
- Implement that in your code

Step 3:

- Load the font with:

  - `guard let myFont = UIFont(name: "YourFontName", size: 22.0) else { fatalError("Could not load font!!!) }`
- Use it, for example, for a label:

  - `myLabel.font = myFont`

Tips:

- look at [CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1499468-ctfontmanagerregisterfontsforurl)
- understand that the font's Postscript Name will not always (and usually doesn't) match the font's File Name. For example, there is a font named `Franchise-Regular`, but the file name is commonly `Franchise.ttf`

As you work through those steps, if you run into any ***specific*** problems, come back and ask ***specific*** questions.